# House breaking a 3 month old daschound that has never been in a house before now

Tags: toilet-training

I have a daschound puppy that we bought from a family friend that breeds them it was the last puppy there and has been outside since day one. When we got her she used the bathroom in the house and we figured it was just nerves and she might have been confused because she has never been inside. Well we have had her for almost a month and I still can’t get her potty trained. I will take her outside multiple times a day and every time she refuses to use the bathroom (except for when she has been in her dog crate all night long she will use the bathroom when she is let out. We started keeping her in a crate because we didn’t want her peeing and pooping everywhere during the night). And even sometimes she will run somewhere and immediately starts using the bathroom as soon as we come back inside. She will get scolded for this and taken outside again but she just doesn’t seem to understand. Even when I keep her in a crate all day I will take her outside a few times and she refuses to use the bathroom, she has never peed in her crate but she has pooped in it. I will take her out at night before I go to bed and she will still refuse to use the bathroom so I’ll put her back in (after a full day of not peeing) and then the next morning she will finally use the bathroom the next morning as soon as I let her out and she will pee for the longest time. I did this for a week and every time she used the bathroom in the morning I would praise her and give her a treat. Well I let her stay out of the crate after that week hoping she learned where to use the bathroom but she immediately started going in the house again. I am completely confused as to why she won’t go to the bathroom outside when that’s where she was using the bathroom before we got her, and since she’s been outside from day one I thought it would have come naturally. The house we are currently living at does have other dogs but they are in a different part of the house than us (except for a few of them that belong to someone that just moved out we are holding them until they save up the money to move each one in with them since it’s quite a bit per dog but those dogs are kept in crates and get let out twice a day outside where they use the bathroom they don’t use the bathroom inside and our pup doesn’t really acknowledge that they are even there. The dogs in the other part of the house though are not potty trained outside they are trained to pee on towels that the lady lays down for them (she is to lazy to take them outside) but I don’t think that would confuse our dog since she’s not even in the same room as them. There are also dogs outside But our dog doesn’t have a problem with them they just do the occasional sniffing and then the outside dogs go on their way sometimes they play a little bit when they don’t my dog will just sit down at me feet/on my feet if I try to move away she runs to me and sits back down. I’ve even tried just walking and spent hours at a time outside and she still doesn’t go she will hold it until we are back inside (I’ve learned to carry her back inside and straight to the crate because if I don’t she will immediately run somewhere to use the bathroom before I can get her). If anyone knows why she is having such a problem using the bathroom outside I would love to know and anyone that has pointers on how to train her or if I’m doing something wrong please help!

Comment: When you go outside, wait until she goes and make a party when she does (do this after she has been crated and you know she will go), if she goes inside stern NO if you catch her right away and take her outside, otherwise just clean it up... Its not an overnight thing, it will take time for her to get it, and remember she is a puppy, they cant control their bladders very well...have patience and be consistent, also if she goes inside use a special cleaner to get rid of the scent, or she will go on there again

Comment: How does it look outside? Is there some grass and trees or is everything paved and concreted? And you should *really* edit your question and format it into a few paragraphs to make it easier to read.